# Change "Documents" location (without right clicking)

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I know how to normally change the location of Documents, Music, etc. This time however I need a different way.

I did a clean install of Windows 10 and set the locations to `D:Documents`, `D:Music`, etc. These were accepted as valid locations, but if you notice are missing a backslash `\`. This causes many applications to act weird when trying to access those locations. When I try to change it by right clicking on the folder and go to properties, all of Windows explorer freezes and I have to restart it.

So is there any way to change the locations of these folders? Perhaps in the registry or something? I'd hate to have to do another clean install of Windows just for this.

Answer (score 1):

Already figured it out! The keys needed are located at:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Change from there, restart explorer, and the problem is solved!